# How to add a ForeignKey to an unmanaged model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models as shown below:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed=False


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    match = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I run migrations, I get the below error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "client" does not exist
```

How can I fix this? I am using django 3.1 and Postgres 12 as my production db.

Answer (score 1):

See here - https://riptutorial.com/django/example/4020/a-basic-unmanaged-table-

The problem may have been caused because of the following:

1. By managed=False, Django won't be able to manage the modal. It won't run any migrations on this. But you must have this table which you can create using SQL query.
2. Second and the most important thing, this table which you have created using SQL must be named myapp_client where "myapp" is the name of the app in which this modal is located.

UPDATE -
Now follow along very carefully.

1. Please don't get confused with the word dummy. In the above article, this dummy is the name of the model which is in your case client.
2. makemigrations command (in informal words) converts the model to an SQL query. Whenever there is another change in the models, a new migrations file will be created storing the query for the modification.
3. migrate - This command actually creates the tables in the database. Check your setting.py file. You must have specified the name of the database. When you run this command, all the tables will be created in this database.
4. There is a conventional way in which Django stores the tables in the database. It names every table starting with the name of the app appended by a '_' + name of the model.
   For example - Let's say there is an app named Shop inside of which, in the models, you have Client and Store table. On running the above command, Django ORM will automatically create tables named shop_client and shop_store.
5. What happens when you used managed=False -
   Django does not manage any migrations files for the table marked with managed=False. It will manage the migrations files of other models which have not been marked as "managed=False".
6. But ultimately, you have to have all the tables in the database with the conventional name. So, you'll have to create those tables(managed = False) through SQL queries or better phrased all the modifications to this table using SQL.
   Taking the earlier example. There are two models in the Shop app. managed=False has been specified for client but store model is as it is. Django will create or modify only shop_store and won't touch shop_client. You will have to do all the modifications, creation or deletion through your SQL query.

Knowing all this, it will be completely fine if you are able to do all these things by yourself when you have specified managed=False for the table. Just follow the conventions used by Django and replicate the process and your thing will work.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info. But I am little unclear with the details provided in that article. So I create a dummy view of my 'Client' model? Would that help me create a model named 'Store' containing a foreign key?

Comment: It can be a view or a table which you'll create using SQL query. "dummy" in the article corresponds to "client" in your code. Store model is anyway managed by django and will be created automatically when you run makemigrations and migrate. But, you'll have to create the myapp_client table or view before running the migrations.

Comment: So in place of the Client table, should I run the inspectdb command so that the dummy table/view is in my models.py file and then run migrations? I'm sorry I'm still unable to figure this out.

Comment: @Code_Sipra Should I run the inspectdb command so that the dummy table/view is in my models.py file and then run migrations? - No need as far as you follow the convention for the naming of the table and its fields, it should be fine.

Comment: I created a view with name tours_client where tours is the name of my app and client is the name of my model. But I still get the same error as stated in the question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE tours_client(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50)); - Use this command to create the table. It works very well for me.

Comment: But I do not want another table in my db. The client table is an already existing table used in production. I want to link this table via a foreign key using the Store model in django.

Comment: Then make sure you have tables or views in the same database. It works for me. The error means that it Django is not being able to find the client table. the sequence also matters. First, create the view and then run the Django commands.

Comment: @Code_Sipra and anyone else - it's *not necessary* to name the table with the application name as a prefix. Simply add the actual table name to the `Meta` class using `db_table` attribute. E.g. `db_name = 'client'`.